# Migrating WFFM to Sitecore 9 Forms Module

Tags: wffm, migration, sitecore-forms

We are currently on Sitecore 7.5, using Mongo for xDB and also using WFFM Module.

Planning for an upgrade to Sitecore 9 soon. Where the Sitecore Forms Module looks promising and apart from few custom save action most of the WFFM features we are using as of now are available with Forms module.

Wanted to check if there is a possibility to migrate WFFM to Sitecore Forms. If not, do we have any plans to facilitate this in near future.

Also until then is it recommended to use both Sitecore Forms and WFFM on the same Sitecore 9 instance?

Comment: Update from October 2019: There is present [non-official open source tool](https://github.com/afaniuolo/WFFM-Conversion-Tool) that can migrate Sitecore WFFM to Sitecore Forms. It could drastically speed up upgrade process.

Comment: Oh yes! I have seen a demo from my friend Alessandro. The tool is promising, I definitely recommend if someone is planning to migrate WFFM to Forms.

Comment: Moderator has converted my answer to comment. But there is still presence "Because of the nature of differences between WFFM and Sitecore Forms, I am fairly confident there is no upgrade/migration path." as answer....
Strange decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sitecore Forms and WFFM are 2 different modules that happen to handle the same functionality (forms). There is no migration path available and at the moment there is no mention of anything like that either (on the contrary - when asked the Forms team said this was nowhere on the roadmap because the modules are too different).

I have a website running on 9 at the moment with WFFM installed. As Forms is installed out-of-the-box, we have both modules available at the same time and this works perfectly. How we will proceed in the future is not yet clear - depends on what Forms will bring in the next updates. Whether it is recommended to use both in the same solution is a difficult question and might be opinion based. Forms is still missing some functionality so you might want to turn to WFFM in that case. Explaining your customer when to use whoich Forms module might be tricky in some cases...

Note however that someday WFFM will truly be dead (now it's end-of-life..). This will not happen before Forms somehow has all the functionality that WFFM has today. But I can't imagine that Sitecore would want to keep 2 teams alive for the same functionality so I assume (note that this is just my guess) that replacing WFFM completely is high on the roadmap for Forms.

But even at that point, don't expect a migration...

Comment: Thanks for the details. 

Truly agree and hope that until Forms Module features all of the functionalities supported by WFFM, the module will not be discontinued. 

But on the other hand if there is no migration tool planned than I am worried about the existing WFFM Form Data, its integration with Marketing automation and personalization in place. 

Though we can recreate the existing forms on Sitecore 9 Forms later but seems it looses all the historical data.

Comment: Forms data might not be converted, but if that data is also available in the profile (as facets or something) you can still use it.

Comment: It has been officially confirmed that Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 is the last version of Sitecore that will support WFFM. Sitecore 9.1 is incompatible with WFFM.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the nature of differences between WFFM and Sitecore Forms, I am fairly confident there is no upgrade/migration path.

That said, I do not see why both WFFM and Sitecore Forms can't co-exist.I would just be aware of how the MVC Form component is utilized.

Answer (score 1):

The intended migration path for going to Sitecore Forms from WFFM is not an automated one. WFFM is available in Sitecore 9 in order to provide coverage for gaps in features but also to ease your upgrade path to Sitecore 9. Once upgraded to Sitecore 9, you can start moving forms over at your own pace, or just developing new ones in Sitecore Forms and keep running your old ones in WFFM until WFFM is retired.