# Sitecore Forms with User Control(.ascx)

Tags: sitecore-forms

Currently using Sitecore 9.0.1 and want to use Sitecore Forms module. Is there a way to use Sitecore Forms using `User Control(.ascx)`?

Tried using MVC https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html and it's working. But there is no documentation for user control (Sublayouts - .ascx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sitecore forms module doesn't support web forms, you will have to use MVC if you want to install and use it in your sitecore solution.

For sitecore 9.0 however you can still use the old web forms for marketers module `https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers.aspx`, which works with web forms. You can take a look at the sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/web-forms-for-marketers/en/insert-a-web-form-directly-on-a-web-page.html.

If you plan to use WFFM note that it works only until 9.0 as stated in the doc: `Web Forms For Marketers was deprecated with the release of Sitecore XP 9.1`. You will also have problems when doing the upgrade as OOTB is not supported and you'll have to use a custom tool to migrate data from WFFM to Forms, as answered here [Migrating WFFM to Sitecore 9 Forms Module](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/migrating-wffm-to-sitecore-9-forms-module).

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore 9 forms doesn't support web forms, for sitecore 9.0.1 either you can use Sitecore WFFM module, but if you are planning to upgrade your sitecore instance in that case this will also depricated.