Sitecore Forms 9.2 compatibility with Webforms
I am in process of migrating existing Sitecore 8.2 application to 9.2
The entire application is based on Webforms and there is no MVC used.
There are few WFFM forms which I need to migrate/rewrite in new application.
Content and code migration has been done and now I am focusing on forms migration.
I created a new form using Sitecore Experience Forms and tried to render it by replacing existing WFFM form in page. Its does not work and throws exception.
Is it really possible to render Sitecore Experience forms in non-MVC appication? And if its possible then what rendering I should use?
Thanks in advance

Sitecore Experience Forms is not compatible with WebForms, it is MVC only

I did not work on web forms but this link may give you some understanding.
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/migrating-wffm-to-sitecore-9-forms-module

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

No, Sitecore MVC forms are not compatible with an ASP.NET site build using Sitecore. There are a couple of reasons for this:
Technology preference: Sitecore itself has transitioned towards using MVC as its primary framework. While ASP.NET Webforms can still be used in conjunction with Sitecore, it's not the recommended approach for new projects.
Architectural differences: Sitecore MVC forms are designed to work within the context of Sitecore's rendering pipeline and data infrastructure.  ASP.NET Web Forms has its own way of handling forms and data, which might not integrate seamlessly with Sitecore's functionalities.
